# How to add a Note to a Contact record using the Partner API

Tags: contact, notes

Quick Information:

- I'm using Partner API
- This is a .NET 4.5 application, C#
- I'm not displaying create() or SaveResult[], or any other Salesforce code

Goal:

- Add a Note to a Contact record using the Partner API

The following returns an error stating, "[contact's id] is not a valid Salesforce ID for the type Note (INVALID_ID_FIELD)." I've tried adding the ParentId node and setting it's value to the contact's ID to no avail. Do I need to create the Note, and then (using the ID in the SaveResult collection) add it to the Contact record? I thought I could "tell" the Note who it belongs to by specifying the Contact ID.

Thank you!

Tyler

```
    sObject salesforceNote = new sObject();

    salesforceNote.type = "Note"
    salesforceNote.Id = contactModel.Id; <-- Pretty sure this is wrong

    XmlDocument requestData = new XmlDocument();

    XmlElement title = requestData.CreateElement("Title");
    title.InnerText = noteModel.Title;

    XmlElement body = requestData.CreateElement("Body");
    body.InnerText = noteModel.Body;

    salesforceNote.Any = new XmlElement[] { title, body };
```

Comment: Have you just tried `contactModel.Id`? I would expect ParentId to refer to the Contact's Account.

Comment: Sorry about that. It's supposed to be contactModel.Id. I updated my code snippet. Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to set the parentId field to the Id of the contact, not the Id of the note, e.g.

```
sObject salesforceNote = new sObject();

salesforceNote.type = "Note"

XmlDocument requestData = new XmlDocument();

XmlElement title = requestData.CreateElement("Title");
title.InnerText = noteModel.Title;

XmlElement body = requestData.CreateElement("Body");
body.InnerText = noteModel.Body;

XmlElement parentId = requestData.CreateElement("ParentId");
parentId.InnerText = contactModel.Id;

salesforceNote.Any = new XmlElement[] { title, body, parentId };
```

In addition you should get set up with one of the schema explorer tools, it'll make working this stuff out easy. (Force.com IDE, Apex explorer etc, there's a bunch)

Comment: Oh man! I added the ParentId node earlier, but I forgot to add it to the array. Thank you very much! Thanks for your tip on the schema explorers, too.